# Gwt hosted mode stopped working from Eclipse on adding a special dependency via maven

Tags: gwt, maven, gwt-hosted-mode

On integrating a library on server side of my gwt app (maven, gwt 2.4) the development/hosted mode stopped working. The app works fine if deployed or run with "gwt:run" and all unit tests and integration tests pass as before. 
If i start development mode (run/debug as web application) from Eclipse the develpoment mode view pops up but nothing else happens. normally the console should show some output but console keeps empty. So i don't even have a hint whats going wrong.
Can someone give some advice where to look / what to do to get at least a hint what's wrong?

if i check out the revision before integrating the library the development mode works! - at the moment i add the dependency (only adding not using it) it stops working.

Background about library i added (don't know if my problem relates to this):I had some problem on integrating the library. the library uses eclipse birt charting engine. This engine has a dependency to Apache derby db, this conflicted with another library. i solved this by excluding the derby dependency via maven. the second problem was a "command line too long" error on unit test - this was solved by updating the maven-surefire-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was hard but the solution is simple: **With Java 7 it is working**!

The problem could be reproduced on 2 of 3 machines. The machine without the problem is the only one that uses java 7. So i installed java 7 on my machine and linked eclipse to it - now hosted mode (from eclipse) works again :-).